# Aurelia bind JSON to component array with default object properties retained

Tags: json, typescript, aurelia

I am trying to do the following:

```
<my-component myobjarray.bind="[{a: 'ID'}, {b: 2}]"></my-component>
```

---

```
@customElement('my-component') 
export class MyComponent
{    
    @bindable myobjectarray: MyObject[] = [];
}
```

---

```
@inject(MyComponent)
@customElement('my-object') 
export class MyObject
{    
    constructor(component: MyComponent) {
    }
    @bindable a:string = 'Hello';
    @bindable b:number = 1;
}
```

The issue is after MyComponent.myobjectarray binds myobjectarray has the following values in it because I just sent in a normal JSON object but I want it to be of type MyObject without actually specifying it as such when I pass it in to my-component:

```
[0] a = "ID", b????
[1] a????, b = 2
```

I would like it to revive the object on bind so it has the default values and looks like this: (Actually types of MyObject)

```
[0] a = "ID", b = 1 (default value)
[1] a = "Hello" (default value), b = 2
```

OPTIONALLY it would be ok if I did the mapping myself in bind or something similar but I cannot create a new instance of MyObject(this) in MyComponent but Aurelia errors and won't let me inject MyComponent into MyObject. (Not sure how to do this either but I would like to know)

Comment: JavaScript is not a typed language. There is no way to infer a type when you pass in JSON. In either case, binding to JSON is not a good idea, and when you give it as an example, its hard to understand where you're going with the example.

Comment: I realize JS is not typed. Binding to a property that contains JSON data is not a good idea? It is extremely common to have a web service return JSON data where the data needs to be bound to a control and be rendered out as a list of items in a dropdown or as a list of rows in a data table. You can think of "MyComponent" as a dropdown and "MyObject" as a drop down item for the sake of discussion. Based on my answer I want to either hard code the items in the drop down with the nesting of my-component/my-object OR get items from WS (JSON Data) maintaining MyObject property defaults !specified.

Comment: > It is extremely common to have a web service return JSON data

Yes. But then you parse it with `JSON.parse` and it's an object. There's no point in getting a JSON string from a web service and binding it in your view without parsing it. And therefore, this example has is hard to understand.

Comment: It is obvious you are hung up on why I am passing in JSON as a string but it is nothing more than a shortcut to make the question shorter. Even with this example using .bind there on that "string" gives perfectly valid JSON array of objects by time it is bound / gets to myobjectarrayChanged(value) in the MyComponent view-model. Without .bind yeah it would be a worthless string. I could have very well included a full service and such but it isn't relevant to the question.  Already figured out ways to do what I wanted so thanks anyway. Best way to do it? No idea.

Comment: If you pass in JSON, it's obviously going to be JSON. If you pass in an object, that object could (should) have already been parsed as a MyObject.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it the "Optional" way I wanted it done which is a ridiculous amount of work to get something like this working. It would be better if bind could just auto add sub components (without typing them into the template) when they are not complete JSON objects of the sub component type. **I am still open for a better/proper way to do this** but this is my current solution:

In MyComponent add:

```
    constructor(private bindingEngine:BindingEngine, private viewCompiler:ViewCompiler, private viewSlot:ViewSlot, private container:Container, private resources:ViewResources){
    }

    myobjectarrayChanged(value) {        
        this.myobjectarray = [];
        var item:any;
        var sItems = '<template>';
        for(let item of value){
            sItems += `${'<my-object'}
                ${item.hasOwnProperty('a') ? ' a="' + item.a + '"' : ''}
                ${item.hasOwnProperty('b') ? ' b="' + item.b + '"' : ''}
                ${'></my-object>'}`;
        }
        sItems += '<template>';

        var viewFactory =  this.viewCompiler.compile(sItems, this.resources);
        var bindingContext = null; 
        var view = viewFactory.create(this.container, bindingContext);
        this.viewSlot.add(view);
        this.viewSlot.attached();
    }
```

And in MyObject add this to the constructor:

```
component.myobjectarray.push(this);
```

**This makes it so you can specify your component like:**

```
<my-component myobjarray.bind="[{a: 'ID'}, {b: 2}]"></my-component>
```

OR

```
<my-component>
    <my-object a='ID'></my-object>
    <my-object b='2'></my-object>
</my-component>
```

Which is what I was trying to make happen.